# Composite primary keys which are also foreign keys in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

If I have 2 tables 1 with a composite primary key where one of the keys is also a foreign key in another table:

Table 1:

- A (PK, FK - maps to X in Table 2)
- B (PK)
- C

Table 2:

- X (PK)
- Y

Because A is both the PK in table 1 and FK in table 2, when I use EF to generate the entity model, I have both a **Scalar** AND a **Navigation** property for A in table 1.  I cannot seem to remove A as a scalar (I think because it is a primary key).

The problem I am having is that if I create a table1Entity and set A's scalar property to a new value, A's navigation property will not be changed automatically (and vice versa).

Ideally I just want A to expose the navigation property - which is the way it behaves if A was not also part of the composite primary key anyway.  Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Am I correct in assuming that Table1 derives from Table2?  If so, I would do it like so:

(I'd also change the PK for both tables to the same name, since they probably have the same meaning - for the instance of this, I'll use the example ID)

- First, create the model with the default relationships (I usually just import the two tables from the database)
- In the designer, right click the base type, add inheritance, select the derived type.
- Delete the one to zero or one association
- Then, since the base type already has column ID, delete it from the derived type.
- Go to table mapping for the derived type, and map the ID property to the ID of the table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike.  Actually there is no inheritance relationship, there are simply a number of tables whos primary key form a composite key on another table.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not really. Create the view with schemabinding and create a clustered index on the view (SQL Server 2008 or later, earlier versions I'm not sure can do that). The clustered index will be recognised as a primary key, thus tricking EF(VS) into believing the view is a real table.

Answer (score 1):

Have you expicity set the Ids of the composite key and referenced these in your configuration?

i.e

```
public class Table1
{
public Table2 A{get;set}
public int AId {get;set;}

public int BId {get;set;}
}
```

I assume you'll need something like:

```
HasKey(pc => new { pc.AId, pc.BId});
HasRequired(x => x.A).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.AId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mapping to table 1 directly, add a view to your database that's got all of table 1's fields, plus an extra copy of A (A2).
Then, map the scalar key to A2 and the nav key to A.

(You'll run into a problem where if you use a view, Visual Studio can't find a primary key; fix this by manually editing the XML of the edmx file and adding a <Key><PropertyRef ... /></Key> to the <EntityType> for table A)

I know - it's hacky and horrible... but hey - it works!

Comment: Well, not really. Create the view with schemabinding and create a clustered index on the view (SQL Server 2008 or later, earlier versions I'm not sure can do that). The clustered index will be recognised as a primary key, thus tricking EF(VS) into believing the view is a real table.